# How to rename sub-subdirectories in Python?

Tags: python, subdirectory

I saw a few posts asking how to rename subdirectories, specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31794787/rename-subfolders-in-a-directory-python), and I want to do something similar for sub-subdirectories. I am making a dataset which cannot have sub-subdirectories. So far, here is what I've tried out with an outline:

```py
'''
In the data/ directory,
For each subdirectory
    For each sub-subdirectory
        Rename it to '{sub_dir}_{subsub_dir}' # So I know which subdir the subsubdir came from
        Take the subsub_dir out of the sub_dir, and place it in 'data/'
    After the inner loop, the subdir should be empty and we can remove it
'''

PATH = r'data' # Relative path
for s in os.listdir(PATH):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(PATH, s)
    for ss in os.listdir(subdir_path):
        pprint(f'Before: {ss}')
        ss = f'{s}_{ss}' # 
        pprint(f'After: {ss}')
        os.rename(os.path.join(subdir_path, ss), os.path.join(PATH, ss))
    # os.remove(subdir_path) # Commented out for safety
```

`data` is a relative path if that makes a difference. VSCode has an option where I can copy the relative path of a folder, so I didn't write this out manually.

However, when I try this I get:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'data\\1\\1_1' -> 'data\\1_1'`

`'data\\1_1'` is what I want the subsubdirs to be renamed to (so they become subdirs). I thought just doing the same thing described in the post I linked but in a nested loop wouldn't make a difference, but I get this error.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Pathes with double backslashes are invalid. Also, try to use an absolute path because relative paths may not point to the expected location.

Comment: Is this specific to Windows paths? Before whenever I made the paths raw string, I could use them. I also just tried an absolute path, I get the same error.

Comment: @MichaelButscher The "double backslashes" in the output are the string representation of a backslash character. Note the quotes which tell us it is a string, not the raw data.

Comment: @hbhutta Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

You are rewriting the variable of `ss` to the new file name before you actually change it. Generally in a `for` loop you do not want to change the variable holding the iterated value, in this case `ss`. Instead, create a new variable to hold the new name you want to use:

```
PATH = r'data' # Relative path
for s in os.listdir(PATH):
    subdir_path = os.path.join(PATH, s)
    for ss in os.listdir(subdir_path):
        pprint(f'Before: {ss}')
        new_ss = f'{s}_{ss}'
        pprint(f'After: {new_ss}')
        os.rename(os.path.join(subdir_path, ss), os.path.join(PATH, new_ss))
```

Comment: As a side note, it is generally a Bad Idea(TM) to reassign any variable to reuse it for a different purpose that it was originally created for. The for loop variable is just a specific example of this more general concept.